# Как правильно создать Json на PHP и отправить на Android

Tags: json, php, java, android

В php файле обращаюсь к базе с запросом на выборку из таблицы "Tests", достаю из неё все значения поля "name".
Далее мне нужно сформировать Json со значениями "name", отправить на Android и распарсить.

Как правильно создать Json хранящий в себе все значения "name" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря в каком виде хотите получить, массив:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `Tests`");
$arr;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $arr[] = $row['name'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Массив Объектов:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `Tests`");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $objs[$i] = new StdClass();
    $objs[$i]->name = $row['name'];
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($objs);
```

Для распарсивания JSON в Java рекомендую Gson. Для запросов к серверу Jsoup или ApacheHttpClient.

Comment: $json = json_encode(mysql_fetch_row()); // получаем индексный массив и зная об этом факте в пункте приемки используем соответственно. ассоциации тут не стояли.

Comment: Во втором варианте (Массив Объектов) вывод только один объект

Comment: @kokahko, тупанул слегка, поправил :)

Comment: В первом варианте получаю такой ответ:
["test2","test1"]
Во втором:
[{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test1"}]

Не могу понять какой использовать лучше так как не могу разобраться с парсером (